# How to define an rdfs:range target in a list of possibilities?

Tags: syntax, rdf, owl, protege, rdfs

I'm trying to declare a property `phs:hasTheValue`  to add a boolean or an integer to an object.

Currently, I've wrote this code to define the property.

```
phs:hasTheValue a rdf:Property;
    rdfs:range [
            a owl:DataRange;
            owl:oneOf (xsd:boolean xsd:integer);
        ];
    .
```

My problem is that I can't open my file with Protégé 5.0 because of the `owl:oneOf` assertion. Is this a wrong syntax or a wrong way to declare the `rdfs:range` of my property ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this is not working is because `owl:oneOf` is defined as:

> An enumeration is a owl:oneOf element, containing **a list of the objects that are its instances**. 
>   This enables us to define a class by exhaustively enumerating its elements. The class defined by the oneOf element contains exactly the enumerated elements, no more, no less. For example:

```xml
<owl:oneOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
<owl:Thing rdf:about="#Eurasia"/>
<owl:Thing rdf:about="#Africa"/>
<owl:Thing rdf:about="#North_America"/>
<owl:Thing rdf:about="#South_America"/>
<owl:Thing rdf:about="#Australia"/>
<owl:Thing rdf:about="#Antarctica"/>
</oneOf>
```

What you are trying to define does not fit into the definition of `owl:oneOf`. I think what you need is a normal union.

```xml
<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.org/demo.owl#hasTheValue">
    <rdfs:range>
        <rdfs:Datatype>
            <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                <rdf:Description rdf:about="&xsd;boolean"/>
                <rdf:Description rdf:about="&xsd;integer"/>
            </owl:unionOf>
        </rdfs:Datatype>
    </rdfs:range>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>
```